# Reading a load cell on an NI 9219 using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, labview

I'm trying to read a loadcell from a NI cDAQ 9174 that has a NI 9219 module in the first slot (of the cDAQ 9174) but I am receiving this error:

```
In [1]: runfile('C:/Users/Desktop/Testing/Training/Python/Spyder Data 
Analysis/Loadcells/Load cell trial.py', 
wdir='C:/Users/Desktop/Testing/Training/Python/Spyder Data 
Analysis/Loadcells')
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-1-2d4c817735fa>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('C:/Users/Desktop/Testing/Training/Python/Spyder Data 
Analysis/Loadcells/Load cell trial.py', 
wdir='C:/Users/Desktop/Testing/Training/Python/Spyder Data 
Analysis/Loadcells')

File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 668, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 108, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "C:/Users/Desktop/Testing/Training/Python/Spyder Data 
Analysis/Loadcells/Load cell trial.py", line 35, in <module>
custom_scale_name=None)
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\nidaqmx\_task_modules\ai_channel_collection.py", line 743, in 
add_ai_force_bridge_table_chan
    min_val, max_val, units.value, bridge_config.value,

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'value'
```

The thought is the load would show on the graph until 30 samples are taken and stop. I can however read another module from the NI 9174 the 3rd module (NI 9211) that has 3 thermocouples without any issue and the graph will read the thermocouples (30 samples and stop).

The API provides a couple of different ways to add a force measurement channel and I've tried a few and still get no reading.

Reference here: https://nidaqmx-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ai_channel_collection.html

Ideally, I'd like to use the `.add_ai_force_bridge_table_chan()` method because I have a calibration table to add the information but when I got the error above I also tried the `add_ai_force_bridge_two_point_lin_chan()` but also received an error. Any help is greatly appreciated!

I also wanted to mention that I have a LabVIEW program that will read the loadcell so it does work. The idea is to eventually bring all the control into Python so I can speed up my post-test data analysis and also I thought it would be fun!

Thermocouple code that works:

```
#import the national instrument wrapper and plotting
import nidaqmx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#keep the plat from closing between data sets
plt.ion()

i = 0

#code portion to read from the NI instrument
with nidaqmx.Task() as task:
    task.ai_channels.add_ai_thrmcpl_chan("cDAQ3Mod3/ai0:2")

    while i<30:
        data = task.read(number_of_samples_per_channel=1)
        plt.scatter(i,data[0],c='r')
        plt.scatter(i,data[1],c='b')
        plt.scatter(i,data[2],c='g')
        plt.pause(0.05)
        plt.show()
        i=i+1
        print(data)
```

Loadcell code that gives the error:

```
import nidaqmx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#keep the plat from closing between data sets
plt.ion()

i = 0

#code portion to read from the NI instrument
with nidaqmx.Task() as task:
#adding linear table of values for load cell reading: loadcell SN 666133
task.ai_channels.add_ai_force_bridge_table_chan("cDAQ3Mod3/ai0", 
name_to_assign_to_channel="Loadcell",
            min_val=-4000.0, max_val=4000.0, units= 15876,
            bridge_config=10182,
            voltage_excit_source=10200,
            voltage_excit_val=2.5, nominal_bridge_resistance=350.0,
            electrical_vals= [-19183, 0, 0.3383, 0.7703, 1.1525, 1.535, 
1.9183],
            electrical_units=15897,
            physical_vals=[-4000, 0, 800, 1600, 2400, 3200, 4000], 
physical_units=15876,
            custom_scale_name=None)

    while i<30:
        data = task.read(number_of_samples_per_channel=1)
        plt.scatter(i,data[0],c='r')
        #plt.scatter(i,data[1],c='b')
        plt.pause(0.05)
        plt.show()
        i=i+1
        print(data)
```

Comment: Is that the whole of the error traceback? I'm not familiar with using NI-DAQmx from Python but the immediate cause of the error looks as if the `units` or `bridge_value` parameters ought to be some kind of object which has a `value` property, but instead it's just an integer number. Where did you get the values you're supplying to your `task.ai_channels_add_ai_force_bridge_table_chan` call and are you sure they're correct?

Comment: link: https://nidaqmx-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ai_channel_collection.html

Comment: The values come from theloadcell. :add_ai_force_bridge_table_chan(physical_channel, name_to_assign_to_channel=u'', min_val=-100.0, max_val=100.0, units=<ForceUnits.POUNDS: 15876>, bridge_config=<BridgeConfiguration.FULL_BRIDGE: 10182>, voltage_excit_source=<ExcitationSource.INTERNAL: 10200>, voltage_excit_val=2.5, nominal_bridge_resistance=350.0, electrical_vals=None, electrical_units=<BridgeElectricalUnits.M_VOLTS_PER_VOLT: 15897>, physical_vals=None, physical_units=<BridgePhysicalUnits.POUNDS: 15876>, custom_scale_name=u'')[source]

Comment: @nekomatic Updated my post to include the full traceback

Comment: OK, I'm pretty sure the problem is that the values you're passing in for the parameters like `units`, `bridge_config` and so on are meant to be instances of the [nidaqmx.constants](https://nidaqmx-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/constants.html) class, not just numbers: for example, `nidaqmx.constants.BridgeConfiguration.FULL_BRIDGE`, not `10182`. Does that work?

Comment: Ok, I'll try this and let you know if it works.

Comment: That worked! thank you!

Comment: You might check out TestScript, a fully bidirectional Python/LabVIEW connector written by Wineman Technology: https://www.winemantech.com/testscript-download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Reference here is how it looks now:

```
import nidaqmx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#keep the plat from closing between data sets
plt.ion()

i = 0

#code portion to read from the NI instrument
with nidaqmx.Task() as task:
    #adding linear table of values for load cell reading: loadcell SN 666133
    task.ai_channels.add_ai_force_bridge_table_chan("cDAQ3Mod1/ai0", 
 name_to_assign_to_channel="Loadcell",
        min_val=-4000.0, max_val=4000.0, units= nidaqmx.constants.ForceUnits.POUNDS,
        bridge_config=nidaqmx.constants.BridgeConfiguration.FULL_BRIDGE,
        voltage_excit_source= nidaqmx.constants.ExcitationSource.INTERNAL,
        voltage_excit_val=2.5, nominal_bridge_resistance=350.0,
        electrical_vals= [-1.9183, 0, 0.3383, 0.7703, 1.1525, 1.535, 1.9183],
        electrical_units=nidaqmx.constants.BridgeElectricalUnits.M_VOLTS_PER_VOLT,
        physical_vals=[-4000, 0, 800, 1600, 2400, 3200, 4000], 
physical_units=nidaqmx.constants.BridgePhysicalUnits.POUNDS,
        custom_scale_name=None)

    while i<30:
        data = task.read(number_of_samples_per_channel=1)
        plt.scatter(i,data[0],c='r')
        #plt.scatter(i,data[1],c='b')
        plt.pause(0.05)
        plt.show()
        i=i+1
        print(data)
```